# How does the implementation of ScalaNumber work regarding underlying?

Tags: math, scala, numbers, biginteger, bigdecimal

`scala.math.ScalaNumber` is a Java file which looks like this:

```
public abstract class ScalaNumber extends java.lang.Number {
  protected abstract boolean isWhole();
  public abstract Object underlying();
}
```

And `scala.math.BigDecimal` implements it with:

```
class BigDecimal(val bigDecimal: BigDec, val mc: MathContext)
extends ScalaNumber with ScalaNumericConversions with Serializable {
  ...
  def underlying = bigDecimal
}
```

as well as `scala.math.BigInt`:

```
class BigInt(val bigInteger: BigInteger) extends ScalaNumber with ScalaNumericConversions with Serializable {
  ...
  def underlying = bigInteger
}
```

Confusingly, `underlying` is of type `java.math.BigDecimal`/`java.math.BigInt` instead of `Object`.

Do I miss something pretty obvious or is there something special-cased here?

EDIT: Of course I missed something obvious ... You're all right. Co-variant return types. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is simply a [covariant return type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type), which is allowed both in Scala and Java.

The rationale behind it is: if a class `Base` promises to return `A` form a certain method, then a subclass `Derived <: Base` respects the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) if it returns `A` or any subclass `B <: A`. Certainly, if `BigInt#underlying` returns a `BigInteger`, this is no problem for clients of `ScalaNumber`, who may only hope for a plain `Object`.

Answer (score 4):

In both Java and Scala method return types can be covariant when overriding.  That is to say if you override a method you can make its return type be a subtype of the overriden method's return type.

```
scala> class Foo { def method : Object = "foo" }
defined class Foo

scala> class Bar extends Foo {override def method : String = "bar" }
defined class Bar

scala> (new Foo).method
res0: java.lang.Object = foo

scala> (new Bar).method
res1: String = bar

scala> ((new Bar) : Foo).method
res2: java.lang.Object = bar
```